# rails 3 - How to render a PARTIAL as a Json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to do something like this:

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  def upload
    render :json => { :attachmentPartial => render :partial => 'messages/attachment', :locals => { :message=> @message} }
  end
```

Is there a way to do this? render a Partial inside a JSON object? thanks

Comment: Yes, you should be able to accomplish this. I think you syntax is incorrect though. Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088280/in-rails-how-do-you-render-json-using-a-view for a working version.

Comment: the question is different :) , partial in json, not json in partial

Comment: good catch :) guess I've never tried it that way

Comment: My answer to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15574453/667598

Answer (score 45):

This should work:

```
def upload
    render :json => { :attachmentPartial => render_to_string('messages/_attachment', :layout => false, :locals => { :message => @message }) }
end
```

Notice the **render_to_string** and the underscore `_` in before the name of the partial (because render_to_string doesn't expect a partial, hence the **:layout => false** too).

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to render `html` inside a `json` request for example, I suggest you add something like this in `application_helper.rb`:

```
# execute a block with a different format (ex: an html partial while in an ajax request)
def with_format(format, &block)
  old_formats = formats
  self.formats = [format]
  block.call
  self.formats = old_formats
  nil
end
```

Then you can just do this in your method:

```
def upload
  with_format :html do
    @html_content = render_to_string partial: 'messages/_attachment', :locals => { :message => @message }
  end
  render :json => { :attachmentPartial => @html_content }
end
```

Comment: Just thought I would mention that mbillard's solution only found the partial for me after I added the `.html` postfix to the partial path , I think this might be because it was using a json format by default.

Comment: @CyleHunter that's actually a pretty common use case, I edited my answer to cover this behavior.

Comment: Rails 3.2: You can also set the handler (haml, erb, etc.) in render_to_string, e.g. render_to_string(partial: 'messages/attachment', handlers: [:haml])

Answer (score 12):

This question is a bit old, but I thought this might help some folks.

To render an **html** partial in a **json** response, you don't actually need the `with_format` helper as explained in mbillard's answer. You simply need to specify the format in the call to `render_to_string`, like `formats: :html`.

```rb
def upload
  render json: { 
    attachmentPartial: 
      render_to_string(
        partial: 'messages/attachment', 
        formats: :html, 
        layout: false, 
        locals: { message: @message }
      )
  }
end
```

Comment: This fixed it for me! I wish this extra option was documented :(

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 6 I think this might be a little different from the accepted answer. I don't think you need to set the underscore in the partial name. This worked for me:

```
format.json {
  html_content = render_to_string(partial: 'admin/pages/content', locals: { page: @page }, layout: false, formats: [:html])
  render json: { attachmentPartial: html_content }
}
```