# Rails how to update partial with json response from an ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, request, partial-views

I have an ajax post to my backend rails app, it's to post a upload a file.

Post response with my files list in JSON

After that I need to reload my files list at view detalhes.html.erb page. This list is a partial. Here is what I have:

controller method:

```
  def upload_arquivo
    @ponto_venda = PontoVenda.find(params[:pv_id])
    nome = params[:key].split('/').last
    @arquivo = Arquivo.new(nome: nome, endereco: params[:url], s3_key: params[:key], tamanho: params[:tam], user_id: params[:u_id], tag_id: params[:tag])
    if @arquivo.save!
      ArquivoPontoVenda.create(arquivo_id: @arquivo.id, ponto_venda_id: @ponto_venda.id, fachada: false)
      response = { files: filtro_pv_arquivos, message: "O arquivo '#{nome}' foi salvo" }
    else
      response = { files: '', message: 'Ocorreu um erro ao salvar o arquivo, por favor, tente novamente' }
    end
    render json: response
  end
```

My ajax post method at `_arquivos_upload.html.erb`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some_url,
    type: 'post', processData: false
})
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data.files.length);
    // trying to reload partial after post request
    $('#display-arquivos').html("<%= escape_javascript(render "arquivos_buscados") %>");
});
```

data.files are correct, I just need to find a way to pass this to my render partial. How can I do that? Or if this is a bad way to do it, how can I do better?

Here is where I render my partial `detalhes.html.erb`:

```
<div class="card" id="display-arquivos">
    <%= render "arquivos_buscados" %>    
</div>
```

I already have try a lot of this:

[github link](https://gist.github.com/mrdanadams/2230354)

[set .html(data.files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357897/rails-render-partial-with-json-object)

[use js.erb file logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988556/is-it-possible-to-refresh-partial-frequently-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

That looks good. I'd suggest modifying your partial to accept a local variable and then explicitly passing it in when you render the partial.

```
<div class="card" id="display-arquivos">
    <%= render "arquivos_buscados", locals { files: @files #add this } %>    
</div>
```

`$('#display-arquivos').html("<%= escape_javascript(render "arquivos_buscados", locals: { files : data.files } ) %>");`

Comment: I try this but data.files inside ruby tag return an error = undefined local variable or method `data'.

Comment: @LucasAndrade Any idea, how did you resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think I would render back `html` instead of `json`. Then, in `.success` function of the `ajax` call, just do:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'some_url,
  type: 'post', processData: false
})
.success(function(data) {
  $('#display-arquivos').html(data);
});
```

You'll probably need to change your controller action along the lines of:

```
def upload_arquivo

  ...

  if @arquivo.save!
    ArquivoPontoVenda.create(arquivo_id: @arquivo.id, ponto_venda_id: @ponto_venda.id, fachada: false)
    @files = #populate your @files variable
    render "arquivos_buscados"
  else
    render :something_else
  end

end
```

Comment: I just try this, and my list disappeared. In this partial, when I first load the page html.erb my files are variable named @files