# rails - how to render a JSON object in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

right now I'm creating an array and using:

```
render :json => @comments
```

This would be fine for a simple JSON object, but right now my JSON object requires several helpers which is breaking everything and requiring helper includes in the controller which seems to cause more problems than solved.

So, how can I create this JSON object in a view, where I don't have to worry about doing anything or breaking anything when using a helper. Right now the way I'm making the JSON object in the controller looks little something like this? Help me migrate it to a view :)

```
# Build the JSON Search Normalized Object
@comments = Array.new

@conversation_comments.each do |comment|
  @comments << {
    :id => comment.id,
    :level => comment.level,
    :content => html_format(comment.content),
    :parent_id => comment.parent_id,
    :user_id => comment.user_id,
    :created_at => comment.created_at
  }
end

render :json => @comments
```

Thanks!

Comment: Little confused by "requires several helpers ", what helpers, to do what ?

Comment: the html_format is a helper that users simple_format and auto_link. That's where all the trouble is.

Comment: Follow [these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088280/in-rails-how-do-you-render-json-using-a-view/2088378#2088378)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend that you write that code in an helper itself. Then just use the `.to_json`
method on the array.

```
# application_helper.rb
def comments_as_json(comments)
  comments.collect do |comment|
    {
      :id => comment.id,
      :level => comment.level,
      :content => html_format(comment.content),
      :parent_id => comment.parent_id,
      :user_id => comment.user_id,
      :created_at => comment.created_at
    }
  end.to_json
end

# your_view.html.erb
<%= comments_as_json(@conversation_comments) %>
```

Comment: Wait... Does being inside a helper mean that it can use things like simple_format, etc w/o needing includes?

Comment: If I did this with the fact that html_format uses simple_format and auto_link be a problem?

Comment: I assume you found that answer yourself by now - but yes, you don't need to explicitly include other helpers within a helper. Note: This requires that your ApplicationController has `helper :all` (default).

Answer (score 27):

Or use:

```
<%= raw(@comments.to_json) %>
```

to escape out any html encoding characters.

Comment: tested and it seems safe, e.g. `"</script><script>alert(1)</script>` becomes `"\u003c/script\u003e\u003cscript\u003ealert(1)\u003c/script\u003e"`

Answer (score 7):

```
<%= @comments.to_json %>
```

should do the trick too.