# Create a JSON representation of a non-ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a model in a Rails 3.1rc4 application that is not based on ActiveRecord.

```
class Database
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(connection, database_name)
    @connection = connection
    @name = database_name
  end

  def self.all
    connection = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost")
    connection.database_names.map { |db_name| new(connection, db_name) }.sort { |x, y| x.name <=> y.name }
  end
end
```

I want to be able to render this a JSON in a `_list.html.erb` template as follows

```
<script>
  var databases = <%= @databases.as_json %>
</script>
```

The method in the application controller is as follows

```
def populate_databases
  @databases = Database.all
end
```

I am trying to represent the collection of all of the database JSON to be processed by Backbone.js.  However, I cannot seem to figure out the appropriate way to do this.  The code above almost works, but the double-quotes in the results are encoded as `&quot;`.  Also, I would like to be able to only include the `@name` property and not the @connection property.  Can someone please help me determine the appropriate way of coding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem implementing a variation of this answer: [rails - how to render a JSON object in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161579/rails-how-to-render-a-json-object-in-a-view/5161619#5161619)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var databases = <%= @databases.as_json %>
```

Is automatically encoding `@databases.as_json` for use in HTML, that's why your double quotes are being converted to `&quot;`. Try using [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) instead:

```
var databases = <%= escape_javascript @databases.to_json %>
```

Also, `as_json` returns a data structure that is ready for conversion to JSON, `to_json` returns the actual JSON string so you might want to fix that up while you're at it; for example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > {:a => 'a'}.as_json
 => {"a"=>"a"} 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > {:a => 'a'}.to_json
 => "{\"a\":\"a\"}"
```