# "There was no default layout for..." in json format response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, xmlhttprequest

I was using a html and json response with the classic `respond_to do |format|` but now I was trying to implement a xhr data load and, after a while searching, this was my solution (with the corresponding js and html templates):

```
respond_to :html, :js, :json
# GET /messages
def index
  @search = Messages.valid.search(params[:search])
  @messages = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  respond_with(@messages, :layout => !request.xhr?)
end
```

The html and js responses works correctly, but now if I want to call something like `/messages.json` it throws me:

```
ArgumentError in MessagesController#index

There was no default layout for MessagesController in [#<ActionView::FileSystemResolver:0x1064c23c0 @caching=false, @path="/Users/alter/workspace/trilog/app/views", @cached={}>]
```

How `respond_with` handle these kind of data types? And what should I do to make responses in all the different format types?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

As appears [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088280/in-rails-how-do-you-render-json-using-a-view) 
I've added a `index.json.haml` template with only one line `=@messages.to_json.html_safe` but I don't think that add a template for json type would the best solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For JSON, I just use:

```
respond_to do |f|
    f.json { render json: @messages }
end
```

That doesn't really fit in with using `respond_with`, perhaps; what makes the most sense might depend on how many actions, controllers, etc. would need to be modified.

I'll be interested to see what other answers entail.