# how to change json format on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm new to rails, can somebody help me with json format that rails 3.2.2 produce
 I want to know where and how i need to make changes to affect my json otput.
 For example when i click http://localhost:3000/customers.json i got output like this

```
[{"created_at":"2012-03-17T16:10:59Z","id":1,"name":"Jon","phone":"59665","updated_at":"2012-03-17T16:10:59Z"}]
```

, but i need ==>

```
[{"customer":{{"created_at":"2012-03-17T16:10:59Z","id":1,"name":"Jon","phone":"59665","updated_at":"2012-03-17T16:10:59Z"}}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088280/in-rails-how-do-you-render-json-using-a-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to set `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true`

Try setting that in an initializer (config/initializers), restarting your server. You should see the root object appear in your json.

Comment: Can anyone think of a way to override the use of the model class name as the root element (i.e. set include root to true but specify a different name).  I have an external app using the JSON and would rather not have to change my model class name (or change the JSON after the fact or any similar ugliness).

Comment: Answering my own question...apparently as simple as myobj.to_json(:root => "rootname")