# How to change the default json response in devise to custom response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, devise

I use devise for authentication and in registration controller if user cannot be created due to some reason then it produces json response as

> {"email":["has already been taken"],"password":["doesn't match
>   confirmation"],"username":["has already been taken"]}

but i want this to be changed to the following

> {"error":{"email":{"has already been taken"},"password":{"doesn't
>   match confirmation"},"username":{"has already been taken"}}}

How can i do this?

Answer (score 11):

For reference in case anyone else stumbles upon this question when looking for how to customize the json error response when a failed login attempt is made using Devise, the key is to use your own custom `FailureApp` implementation. (You can also use this approach to override some redirect behavior.)

```
class CustomFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    if request.format == :json
      json_error_response
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def json_error_response
    self.status = 401
    self.content_type = "application/json"
    self.response_body = [ { message: "Your email or password is incorrect."} ].to_json
  end
end
```

and in your `devise.rb`, look for the `config.warden` section:

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailureApp
  end
```

Some related info:

At first I thought I would have to override [Devise::SessionsController](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/SessionsController), possibly using the `recall` option passed to `warden.authenticate!`, but as mentioned [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3142), "recall is not invoked for API requests, only for navigational ones. If you want to customise the http status code, you will have better luck doing so at the failure app level."

Also https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Answer (score 3):

Extending from [@quix answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35299895/877028) (I don't leave it as a comment because it has formatting problems).

You can as well minimize overriding just redefining `http_auth_body` method:

```
class CustomFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def http_auth_body
    return super unless request_format == :json
    {
      success: false,
      error: i18n_message
    }.to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: It should be `i18n_message` not `i18_message`.

Comment: This is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You should create a json.erb file and render that in that error.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088280/in-rails-how-do-you-render-json-using-a-view) answer shows you how to do that.

Comment: Actually this "format.json { respond_with_navigational(resource) }" returned the response as i have told, so how can i put this in erb file and how can i change this such that it produces custom response?

Answer (score 0):

```
respond do |format|
    format.json { render json: {error: @your_model.errors }}
end
```

or maybe you should try

```
respond do |format|
    format.json { render json: {error: Hash[@your_model.errors.map {|k, v| k, v[0]] } }}
end
```

Comment: Actually this "format.json { respond_with_navigational(resource) }" returned the response as i have told, so how can change this such that it produces custom response as i have asked for?

Comment: I don't think {"email":{"has already been taken"}} is a valid json format. I suppose what you want is {"email":"has already been taken"}