# ruby hash calling through javascript

Tags: ruby

Below file is  in .html.erb i want to call mash again and again how i do it.I tried many times through setInterval but  it getting old value of data.I am getting new value in  mesh data.but when i see second time calling it takes old.

```
    <%

        mash = {
          "id" => id, "legends" => legends, "x_units" => x_units, "y_units" => y_units, "data" => data, "alertPoints" => alert_points, "time_mode" => time_mode, 
          "colors" => colors, "x_label" => x_label, "y_label" => y_label, "tipColors" => tipColors, "dateformat" => @dateformat, "timeformat" => @timeformat, 
          "chart_url" => chart_url, "x_label_date_format" => x_label_date_format, "turn_series" => turn_series, "y_ticks_array" => y_ticks_array, "y_label_width" => y_label_width,
          "series_type" => series_type,"vertical_threshold" => vertical_threshold, "x_label_suffix" => x_label_suffix, "y_tick_on" => y_tick_on, "xmin" => xmin, "xmax" => xmax
          }
        %>


            <script type="javascript">

                  setInterval(    function ()
                 {
                 onDataReceived(<%=mash.to_json.html_safe%>);



                 }, 5000);
              </script>
```

Comment: how are you fetching your data? What's your ajax callback like? Kinda hard to tell whats wrong without anymore details...

Comment: if use put command to see mash[data] it dynamically change.but <%=mash.to_json.html_safe%> it getting old value .can i call above mash again and again

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `mash` is evaluated once when the page is rendered, so using the erb again and again will always produce the same result. If you want new data, you probably need to request it with AJAX.

[In Rails, how do you render JSON using a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088280/in-rails-how-do-you-render-json-using-a-view)

Docs to make ajax calls with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Ex:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $.get('route/to/mash.json', function(data) {
     onDataReceived(data);
  });
}, 5000);
```